# Is there anything I need to worry about besides SQL injections and XSS attacks?

Tags: php, mysql, security, xss, sql-injection

I'm finishing up my first "real" PHP application and I am trying to make sure it is secure. I'm kind of afraid that since I'm not an "expert" PHP programmer that I might be missing something huge, so I would like to give you some information about my application and hopefully you can tell me whether or not that is the case. So here we go:

- I'm using a CMS to handle user authentication, so I don't have to
  worry about that.
- After discovering PDO shortly after starting work
  on my application, I ported all of my code over to using prepared
  statements with PDO.
- I am escaping all form and database data (even stuff I *think* is safe) which is being output with `htmlentities()`.
- My application does use a session variable and cookie variable, but the function of both is very unimportant.
- I have designed my form processing functions in such a way that it doesn't matter if the form were somehow altered, or submitted from off-server (i.e. I always check the data submitted to ensure it's valid).
- I have done my best to make all error messages and exception messages polite but very obscure.
- I'm forcing pages with sensitive information (such as the login page) to be served over https.

When I first starting writing my application, I didn't know about prepared statements, which is kind of a huge deal. Have I missed anything else?

Comment: Some HTTPS related things 1) Use a real cert, not self signed. There are free ones 2) Use HTTPS for everything and set the strict-transport security flag. Witching to https only for sensitive stuff doesn't work. 3) Mark cookies as "secure"

Comment: @Nate - At least you thinking of security and are covering the bases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OWASP maintains a list of the [Top 10 Most Critical Web Application Security Risks](http://owasptop10.googlecode.com/files/OWASP%20Top%2010%20-%202010.pdf) (warning, PDF download).  This is from 2010, but I think it still applies, perhaps even moreso now.

Injection and XSS are the top two, but you should certainly be aware of the other 8.  If you are using an existing CMS, many of these may already be considered, but the more popular the CMS the more you risk running into vulnerabilities because of black hats trying to find holes in it.

If you are not storing critical data like credit cards, order history, addresses, and even emails, then I wouldn't worry *too* much about your site being affected as long as you are taking the basic precautionary measures (and it sounds like you are).

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about security issues, a good resource is the [OWASP - Top 10 Application Security Risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main)

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to take care in web applications(specially PHPs') is ***[Data Validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation)*** of all the inputs taken from the user which are further saved in your database.

For a secure application, all the transactions should be done on HTTPS. For a secure cookie management ***[Secure and HTTPOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly)*** cookie should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Some more points I don't see mentioned yet. Most of these are not related to code - I am not sure if you only wished for things related to code, but I'll mention them anyway.

- Backups (user data). should be self-evident
- Version control. If you have a big bug, you want to have access to the previous version.
- Audit trail, alarms and logging. If you do get into trouble, how will you find out? Are you able to track down what happened? if you know something is wrong but don't fully know what, are you able to diagnoze the issue?
- Hosting. Where are you hosting? Do you have adequade bandwidth and monitoring? What happens if you get DOSed? Are you able to block out unwanted traffic?
- Caching. Can you change it if needed?

Answer (score 1):

There's always one thing left. Availability :) There are three aspects of security:

- **Confidentiality** (Noone can read what they don't have access to)
- **Integrity** (Noone can change any data what they should have to and you have to be able to detect if it happened even so)
- **Availability** (The data, application whatever has to be available)

You pretty much did a nice job and took care of the first two (credentials, prepared statements, htmlentities...) but none of them will help against a DoS attack. You should be able to detect if someone slaps your site and ban the attackers ip from your server. Although this can be done in PHP (still much better to kick the attacker at the first line of php than let them initialize the framework, database connections etv.) it can be done mre effectively in lower layers (for example: nginx/apache, iptables, snort).

However what you're asking for that usually comes to the matter of risk management. In a real application you're not able to be prepared for all the possible attacks, edge cases etc. What you need to do is classify all the risks by the probability and the impact ( http://www.jiscinfonet.ac.uk/InfoKits/infokit-related-files/Resources/Images/risk-matrix ). With this you can focus on the most important (highest) risks first and probably you can completely ignore the lower bottom part.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Injection and XSS are the most prominent Hacking methods.

You are covered from SQL Injections if you use prepared statements.

Also, if htmlentities() on everywhere you display HTML you should be safe.

Comment: just by using prepared statements does not mean you're safe, you can still use them wrong ([example](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java#Prepared_Statements)). You have to also use them right.

Comment: Similarly, there are situations where it does not suffice to use `htmlentities` alone; it all depends on the context and intend.